# Display a serial number without having the dot considered as a decimal separator

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, numbers, cell

For work, I have a list of cars numbers under the form N.NNN (always 4 numbers with a dot after the first number)
So, for instance 1.578 or 5.247.
There are 2 problems there :

1) The dot is considered as a decimal separator and therfore replaced by a comma "," (I'm in France)... But I don't want this comma ! The "good official way" to write it is with a dot.

2) As the dot is ment to be a decimal separator, if the car got the number 2.200, it will be displayed "2,2"... But we need the "00" after the "2.2"

I got a small VBA code that helps me putting all these numbers in the good format, but this decimal thing is driving me crazy, I searched for a while on the internet without success.

here is the small part of code that could interest you :

```vb
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?, ,-,_,/,\,."   'Defines the special characters we want to get rid of in the Tools codes

On Error Resume Next
For Each Lin In Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:A" & LastCell) 
        CodeVal = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A" & Lin.Row).Value
        'Modify the Short Code to have a point as second character
        For Each Char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")                                              'Deletes all the other special characters possibles, even more... Definition of "SpecialCharacters" at the beginning of this code part
            NewCodeVal = CStr(Replace(CodeVal, Char, ""))
        Next
        If Len(CodeVal) = 4 Then
            CodeVal = Left(NewCodeVal, 1) & Chr(46) & Right(NewCodeVal, Len(NewCodeVal) - 1)
        ElseIf Len(CodeVal) = 3 Then
            CodeVal = Left(NewCodeVal, 1) & Chr(46) & Right(NewCodeVal, Len(NewCodeVal) - 1) & "0"
        ElseIf Len(CodeVal) = 2 Then
            CodeVal = Left(NewCodeVal, 1) & Chr(46) & Right(NewCodeVal, Len(NewCodeVal) - 1) & "00"
        End If
        With Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B" & Lin.Row)
            .Value = CodeVal
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Font.Size = 11
            .Font.Name = Calibri
            .NumberFormat = "##0.000"
        End With

Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

As you've seen, I tried to insert the dot as an ascii character and I tried to use the number formatting without success...

Thank's by advance for your help !

Comment: Isn't it easier to consider car numbers in plain text?

Comment: Agreed with @CommonSense. Please show some example data too, because it feels like you don't start of with a list of text values but numbers. Otherwise your code makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JvdV Yes, it's considered as text at the beginning, but text become numbers really easily in Excel...